# 415 Error: Postman passes, Front end does not

Tags: c#, angular, observable, postman

I have defined a route with order/:orderId and I am trying to hash the orderId to avoid displaying  the real orderId. I looked into ways of hashing and I decided on the 32 bit Mix Function. I have tested the functionality with PostMan and everything works fine, but when accessing the needed endpoint I get a 415 Error. The implementation looks like this:

```
this.orderService.createOrder(newOrder)
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
      ).subscribe(result => {
        console.log(result);
        this.router.navigate(['order', result])
      });
```

And the service looks like this:

```
 createOrder(order:OrderModel): Observable<any> {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/*'
      })
    };
    return this.http.post(this.BASE_URL+'Orders/', order, httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError('createOrder'))
    )
```

The result in subscribe should be the hashed version of the orderId.

Comment: obviosuly reason is `'Content-Type':  'application/*'` ... without server side code we cannot guess what is expected type ... but I'm 90% sure that it should be json (`application/json`)

Comment: Usually I would look at the correct request (sent by Postman), the incorrect request (sent by web app), and compare. What are the differences?

Comment: @Selvin thank you, that was my problem. Missed it

Answer (score 1):

415 status code means unsupported media type, I think sending the content-type as  application/json will solve the problem.

```
Content-type: application/json;
```

Your request should look-like the following

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json'
  })
};
```

Sometimes even if you send the application/json in the request, it doesn't work. In that case you need to check the IIS and add new MIME if not exist.